# Multiprocessing python function that calls a function that returns a value

Tags: python, concurrency, process

I'm trying to parallelize my code but I don't know how to do it properly.
My code is something like this:

```
import my_module

def task(i):
    result = my_module.func(i) #This takes about 30 secs
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor
    executor = ProcessPoolExecutor()
    results = executor.map(task, range(500))
    print(results)
```

But the main program doesn't wait for the result of `my_module.func()`.
Returning something like: generator object _chain_from_iterable_of_lists at 0x.....

How can I make the process to wait the result of `func()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't, and here's why:

The whole idea of multiprocessing/threading is that rather than **wait** on a return statement, you can execute all the necessary code in said function, and using threading, do it all multiple times per second.

That said, if you need it to wait for return data, then maybe you should just not use threading. If you absolutely need to use threading, though, then merge whatever you use the return data for in the function itself.

Comment: Is there any way to speed up a process like that? I need to execute that function about 5000 times. Can I use more cores of my computer? Running the code without multiprocessing only uses 1 core.